# BSOD error 0xc000021a

Tags: windows-8.1, bsod

BSOD error 0xc000021a on windows 8.1 64 bit.

- unable to access safe mood.
- unable to access all the other options in Advanced Boot Options.
- no minidump file for this BSOD.
- I can access Windows 7 in the other partition so I can access to 8.1 files.

I'm not sure but I suspect its the windows update, so I need help how to troubleshoot this.

Comment: Without the ability to boot to **Safe Mode** nor the dump files, we can't help, because you have no provided enough information.  You should backup your files then just install Windows 8.1, doing that, is your only choice honestly.

Comment: I will keep that in mind, but seriously... what is the story of reputations points ? i joined the community to share or at least say my opinion, it makes me feel more stranger ... since i can't comment questions, can't discuss this on meta and can't chat, regardless getting down voted on my questions ? Is this really what the community built for ?

Comment: hi again, this is getting a little bit serious... I just received an other pc - windows 8.1 with same error and same circumstances ... Microsoft said it can occur if **Winlogon.exe** or **Csrss.exe** stops working. This happens if: There were corrupt system files in the computer, There was a failed upgrade or Incomplete installation of a software program.

Comment: is it just a coincidence ? or a bug in latest windows updates.

Comment: This isn't a bug within Windows

Answer (score -2, accepted):

We do need the actual log files (called a DMP files) as they contain the only record of the sequence of events leading up to the crash, what drivers were loaded, and what was responsible.

Please follow our instructions for finding and uploading the files we need to help you fix your computer. They can be found here
If you have any questions about the procedure please ask
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wiki/windows_10-update/blue-screen-of-death-bsod/1939df35-283f-4830-a4dd-e95ee5d8669d

Please read this wiki to find out how to find and upload your event viewer logs
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wiki/windows_10-update/event-viewer-what-is-going-on-in-your-computer/fdda2010-d4df-4fed-863b-89ce0142419d